# Error: 'TypeError: ReactWrapper can only wrap valid elements' when using enzyme.mount

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-wrapper

I'm getting this error when passing a React element to 'mount' function:

```
it("Book - move book to a shelf should work", () => {
    let test = (<Book book={book} />);
    let component = mount(test);
    const select = component.find("select").first();
    expect(select).toBeDefined();
```

However, if I remove the variable and pass the element directly to the method, it works.

```
it("Book - move book to a shelf should work", () => {
    let component = mount(<Book book={book} />);
    const select = component.find("select").first();
    expect(select).toBeDefined();
```

How are they different?

UPDATE:
For some reason, this method (renderer.create from Jest) doesn't complain about that:

```
let component = renderer.create(<Book onMoveBook={onMoveBook} book={book} />);
const tree = component.toJSON(); // Works fine.
```

Also, surprisingly, converting the variable to a function and passing it to **React.createElement** worked:

```
var test = React.createElement(() => <Book onMoveBook={onMoveBook} book={book} />);
let component = mount(test);
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this worked:

    var test = React.createElement(() => <Book onMoveBook={onMoveBook} book={book} />);
    let component = mount(test);

Answer (score 11):

Had the same error. The error is caused by how you are mounting your 'test' component. The way you are doing it, you are not mounting a valid component, but just a variable. You want to put your variable between the `< />` to make it a component.

You are doing `let component = mount(test);` while you should be doing `let component = mount(<test/>);`

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with the actual case of the var `let test`

" components with a lowercased name are DOM elements; custom elements must start with an uppercase letter" 
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/966

I've been drinking from the firehose (somewhat new to enzyme) and remembered seeing this post yesterday however i'm not 100% positive.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue, it was caused by mocking the react module using jest.